# CoverStory reporting 0% coverage after running iPhone app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, unit-testing

I have just started to use the unit testing features in Xcode 4.4.1 with the LLVM Compiler. I have created some basic unit tests. I have attempted to turn on code coverage by turning on the "Instrument Program Flow" and "Generate Test Coverage Files" in the Product section. Also, I have looked through and can't see anything written in the prefix header section. From what I have read in XCode 4.4.1 this is all you have to do to get it to work and it should generate .gcno and .gcda files in the objects-normal/i386 folder which can be opened with CoverStory to view the code coverage. After I quit my app the .gcno files are getting updated but I am not getting any .gcda files. I open the .gcno file in CoverStory which is showing a 0% coverage

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Gcda files are generated when the application exits cleanly. Are you closing the application correctly? Try calling `exit(0)` from your tests/code.

Alternatively this [link](http://code.google.com/p/coverstory/wiki/iOSGCov) suggests either quitting the simulator instead of quitting from Xcode, or adding

```
<key>UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend</key>
<true/>
```

to your plist.